# Python 3.7 input use in threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

Please, can anyone help me to understand why in the following sample code everything I input by the console (I'm using Spyder 4) isn't taken by "input" statement? The main thread exits while the thread containing the input statement goes running forever. The only way to kill it is to reset the Python kernel. Everything goes right if I don't use the input statement.
Thanks for any hint!

```
import threading
import time

class myThread (threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, name, counter):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.name = name
      self.counter = counter
   def run(self):
      print (f"Starting {self.name}")
      wait_input(self.name, 5, self.counter)
      print (f"Exiting {self.name}")

def wait_input(threadName, counter, delay):
    a = input("tell me smthg: ")
    while counter:  
      time.sleep(delay)
      print (f"{threadName}, {time.ctime(time.time())}, {counter}")
      counter -= 1

# Create new threads
thread1 = myThread("Thread-1", 1)

# Start new Threads
thread1.start()
print ("Exiting Main Thread")
```

Comment: please note that while you passing to your myThread class counter=1, you passing counter=5 to wait_input, and delay=1

Comment: I know, what do you mean by that? When I comment the input statement all works fine.

Comment: What happens if you type something into the console and hit enter? Your code's blocking on `input` waiting for you to type something into the console. I don't know Spyder, but maybe it doesn't treat newlines normally...maybe you have to Ctrl+Enter

Comment: If I don't use threads (e.g. only a = input() in the code) I can type anything into the console and that works fine. However I tried Ctrl+Enter but I get the same result: it 's an input to the Python interpreter and is echoed by the console itself.